# Is it possible to use TradingView charts within a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, integration, tradingview-api

Is it possible to use TradingView charts within a Flutter application? Whether it's a mobile or web version?

Comment: use the web view widget and load the chart URL in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WebView Package](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) for displaying anything from the web, this can do the job.